# Java Spring Async Execution

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, jhipster

Using jhipster on spring boot 1.5.4, I'm having a hard time getting background tasks to execute asynchronously; they appear to be running synchronously using a different taskExecutor and thread pool than the one I've configured.

All this happens in a service, which for bevity, is defined like so:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AppService {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
    public void consumeData() {
        // connect to a subscriber and push data to the workerBee
        for(Tuple data : this.getTuples()) {
            workerBee(data);
        }
    }

    @Timed
    @Async
    public void workerBee(Tuple data) throws Exception {
        // ... do something that takes 300ms ....
        Thread.sleep(300);
    }
}
```

Arguably a service isn't the perfect place for this work, but for demonstration purposes, it fits.

(also as an aside, it apears @Timed isn't working, but I read somewhere that @Timed doesn't work when called internally within the service)

Relevant section of `application.yml`:

```
jhipster:
    async:
        core-pool-size: 8
        max-pool-size: 64
        queue-capacity: 10000
```

Using the default, generated AsyncConfiguration.java, which looks like this:

```
@Override
@Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getCorePoolSize());
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getMaxPoolSize());
    executor.setQueueCapacity(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getQueueCapacity());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("app-Executor-");
    return new ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
}
```

I have verified that the taskExecutor bean is getting created and is being used by liquibase.

When I connect visualvm I see all the work happening in `pool-2-thread-1`, which must be some kind of default and it's obvious that the work is happening synchronously, and not asynchronously.

Things I've tried:

- Specifying the executor in the @Async annotation like `@Async("taskExecutor")`
- Verifying configuration of the taskExecutor with 8 threads in the core-pool-size.
- Verifying that the application has the @EnableAsync annotation (it does by default).

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is changing the `@Bean` getAsyncExecutor to this:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor () {
    log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getCorePoolSize());
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getMaxPoolSize());
    executor.setQueueCapacity(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getQueueCapacity());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("app-Executor-");
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what you did here other than remove the ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor wrapper round the executor. Why would/should that help?

Comment: Ignore the answer I just figure out that you are using jhipster

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 2: call the async method in the same class using CompletableFuture**

Here is another approach if you need to use an async  method and call it in the same class using `CompletableFuture` and injecting the `Executor` generated from `AsyncConfiguration`

```
@Service
public class MyAsyncProcess {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAsyncProcess.class);

    @Autowired
    Executor executor;


    @Scheduled(cron = "*/8 * * * * *")
    public void consumeData() {

        IntStream.range(0,20).forEach( (s) ->
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> { return workerBeeCompletableFuture(String.valueOf(s)); } , executor));
    }


    public  CompletableFuture<String> workerBeeCompletableFuture(String data)  {

        log.debug("workerBeeCompletableFuture: Iteration number: " + data + " Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("finished");

    }
```

**Alternative 1 using @Async**

I finally get what is causing this behavior, actually the `@Scheduler` is calling to the `workerBee` as a local method and not as `@Async` method.

In order to make `@Async` work just create a new `@Service` for the `@Schedule` called `MySchedulerService` and `@Autowired` the `AppService` into  the `MySchedulerService`.  Also remove the `@Schedule` from the `AppService` class.

It should be like this:

```
@Service
public class MyAsyncProcess {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAsyncProcess.class);

    @Async
    public  void workerBeeAsync(String data)  {
        // ... do something that takes 300ms ....
        try {
            log.debug("Iteration number: " + data + " Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            log.debug("finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Schedule Service

```
@Service
public class MySchedule {

    @Autowired
    MyAsyncProcess myAsyncProcess;

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/8 * * * * *")
    public void consumeData() {

        IntStream.range(0,20).forEach(s ->
            myAsyncProcess.workerBeeAsync(String.valueOf(s)));

    }

}
```

In the  `application.yml` I use the following values:

```
jhipster:
    async:
        core-pool-size: 50
        max-pool-size: 100
        queue-capacity: 10000
```

The `@Async` will autodetect the `Executor` configured in `AsyncConfigurer` class.

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm not following the rules laid  out here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async. Most notably self-invocation:

@Async has two limitations:

```
it must be applied to public methods only
self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work
```